# Counting a list of strings on every line of multiple files

Tags: bash, grep

I have 250 strings and I need to count the number of times each one appears on every line of my 400 files (which are up to 20,000 lines). Example of strings:

```
journal
moon pig
owls
```

Example of one file:

```
This text has journal and moon pig
This text has owls and owls
```

Example output:

```
1   0
1   0
0   2
```

EDIT: where column one counts strings from the first line of the file, and column two represents the second line of the file.

I have working code but its obviously very slow. I'm sure awk could speed it up but I'm not good enough to write it.

```
for file in folder/*
do
    name=$(basename "$file" .txt)
    linenum=1
    while read line
    do
        while read searches
        do
            ###count every time string appears on line and save
            count=$(echo $line | grep -oi "$searches" | wc -l)
            echo $count >> out/${name}_${linenum}.txt
        done < strings.txt
        linenum=$((linenum+1))
    done < $file
done
```

EDIT: I do 400 pastes like this, where x is the number of lines in the original file.

```
paste out/file1_{1..x}.txt > out/file1_all.txt
```

Does anyone know how to speed this up?

Comment: From your `example of my files` and `example output` it's unclear to me what the columns in the output are meant to correlate to.  Are the two sample lines meant to come from two files, rather than one?

Comment: Do you really want a file with 400 columns as the final result? In case you would sum up the numbers in each row anyway the command might get far easier.

Comment: Likewise, I don't understand "count on every line". Do you want possibly zero counts for all 8 million lines, or counts for lines that only have one or more matches, or counts for files that have any matches. Having an output that tells you only an index of a string, and does not tell you which file had the matches, seems useless. Maybe you could explain what you planned to do with the output next. I would expect to need: "File myName has 50 matches of 7 patterns" and maybe list counts for each separate pattern, and maybe a totals list for all the files together.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to process text data with Bash. If you're dealing with real text, it might be worth using a more advanced language and a real NLP library (e.g. Spacy in Python), because it will take care of a lot of tokenization issues.

Comment: @tink sorry it should say example of one of my files.

Comment: @Socowi actually I want an output file with 400 columns times by linenumber

Comment: @Paul_Pedant It's a bit difficult to explain - I want to know for each of the 400 files, how many lines in each have more words from a collection of 5 types of word (50 within each group). So if the file has 100 lines, 20 of them might have more from one group and 80 of them might have more from a different group.

Comment: @Erwan yes unfortunately my python ability is lacking.

Comment: @SarahM I'm afraid Bash is not the appropriate tool given your volume of data. Virtually any other language will be much faster at this task: C,C++,Java,Python,Perl... it might also give you access to trained tokenizers which will do a better job at word segmentation. The slightly tricky part might be the terms with multiple words in this case. You could also use packages which offer a command-line interface, e.g. CoreNLP (https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/cmdline.html) and probably many others. it's just a suggestion, if you don't really need accurate tokenization it's certainly easier.

Comment: Can you explain your sample output? Why is the count for owls in the 2nd column?

Comment: What @glennjackman said ... if that snippet above is one file I don't get why you have two columns at all ... and if you have 400 files, why do you try and use 500 in the paste?  None of this adds up =/

Comment: @glennjackman The example output is like this:
search  line1  line2 \n
journal  1   0 \n
moonpig 1   0 \n
owls  0   2 \n

Comment: @glennjackman edited my post to try make it clearer

Comment: @tink the 500 is the number of lines in the original file - edited post to try make it clearer

Comment: So your output is a snippet of processing one of your 400 files against 3 lines of the file with strings to be matched?  Each column represents a line of the file grepped, and the lines in the output are the count of each matched word in the respective line?  The paste had no part in any of this yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If

```
$ cat strings
journal
moon pig
owls
```

and

```
$ cat file
I like to journal about owls and moon pigs.
owls are birds. moon pigs are not.
owls owls owls
```

then, you could use GNU awk like this

```bsh
gawk '
    NR == FNR { string[++n] = $0; next}
    {
        for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
            # gsub() return the number of replacements.
            # it is a convenient way to count instances of fixed strings.
            count[i][FNR] = gsub(string[i], string[i])
        if (FNR > max)
            max = FNR
    }
    END {
        for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
            for (j=1; j<=max; j++)
                printf "%s\t", 0 + count[i][j]
            print ""
        }
    }
' strings file
```

outputs

```
1   0   0
1   1   0
1   1   3
```

I haven't explained that awk program at all. See if you can figure it out, and ask any questions you have.

Comment: It works perfectly!!! Thank you so much

Comment: Well, `max` is not really needed, `j<=FNR` is just enough.

Comment: I was thinking that multiple data files would be fed into awk. But that doesn't work with the output format.

Comment: I wrote an answer for multiple file input. Seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

The core algorithm to get an array of counts per each line which processes each line immediately is:

```
gawk ' NR == FNR { string[++n] = $0; next}
       { for (i=1; i<=n; i++) 
             printf("%s\t", gsub(string[i],""))
         print ""
       }
     ' strings file
```

That is based on gsub to giving the count of replacements performed.

That will generate an output of:

```
1   1   0   
0   0   2
```

Which is simply the transposed matrix of what you asked for. It gets a bit complex in awk to transpose columns and rows. And also to process more than one file. We can concatenate (pipe) both scripts using an empty line as indicator of file change. Processing the same file twice:

```
awk '
    NR == FNR { string[++n] = $0; next}
    FNR==1 && p == 1 { print "" }
    { for (i=1; i<=n; i++) printf("%s\t", gsub(string[i],""))
      print ""
      p = 1
    }
    END    { print "" }
' strings.txt    infile.txt    infile.txt |
awk '!/^$/{ 
       for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) f[NR-r][i]=$i ;
       if (maxf<NF) maxf = NF ;
       if (maxr<(NR-r)) maxr = NR-r ;
     } 
     /^$/{
         for(      i=1 ; i<=maxf ; i++ )
         {
             for(  j=1 ; j<=maxr ; j++ )
                 printf("%s\t",f[j][i])
             print ( "loop", maxf, maxr, r )
         }
     r=NR
     print ( "" )
     maxf=0
     maxr=0
     delete f
     }'
```

Which gives the answer as asked:

```
1   0
1   0
0   2

1   0
1   0
0   2
```